# Notepad++ - find and move lines

Tags: notepad++

I have a big language file that has a lot of block like the following:

```
<trans-unit id="common:CommandDescription_EditTest:Manager.CommandDescription.Text">
        <source>Редактировать тест</source><target>Editar prueba</target>
        <alt-trans>
          <target xml:lang="en" state="translated">Edit test</target>
          <target xml:lang="pt" state="x-autotrans">Editar teste</target>
          <target xml:lang="fr" state="translated">Editer test</target>
          <target xml:lang="zh" state="translated">编辑检查</target>
          <target xml:lang="es" state="translated">Editar test</target>
          <target xml:lang="it" state="translated">Modificare test</target>
        </alt-trans>`
```

I need `<target>Editar prueba</target>` to go between `<alt-trans>` tags taking into account that there are a lot of these blocks.

How can I achive that?

Comment: Is `<target>Editar prueba</target>` a constant or could it be any string?

Comment: Could you give more examples and expected result?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(<target>.+?</target>)(\s+)(<alt-trans>)(\s+)`
- Replace with: `$2$3$4$1$4`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(                   # group 1
    <target>            # openning tag
    .+?                 # 1 or more any character, not greedy
    </target>           # closing tag
)                   # end group
(\s+)               # group 2, 1 or more spaces character, including linebreak
(<alt-trans>)       # group 3, openning tag
(\s+)               # group 4, 1 or more spaces character, including linebreak
```

**Replacement:**

```
$2      # content of group 2, spaces for indentation
$3      # content of group 3, openning tag <alt-trans>
$4      # content of group 4, spaces for indentation
$1      # content of group 1, the target tag
$4      # content of group 4, spaces for indentation
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: Looks perfect, but I can't find results. Thanks.

Comment: @Fabri: Sorry, I don't get you, what result can't you find?

Comment: (<target>.+?</target>)(\s+)(<alt-trans>)(\s+) : doesn't give results
https://regex101.com/r/DLBVfE/1


Now working this way : https://regex101.com/r/1MISWo/1

Comment: @Fabri: Well ... as you can see in the screenshots, it works. May be your data are not similar to your given example. Please, edit your question and add more examples and expected result.

Comment: @Fabri: In you test https://regex101.com/r/DLBVfE/1 , you have an extra linebreak at the end of the regex, remove it and it works fine. And use `$2$3$4$1$4` as describe in my answer for the replacement part, [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/NZfieh/1)